# Maven install a multi module project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am developing a .exe application which has muti modules. Everytime there is a small change I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` in the parent module which takes a long time to build which includes web module, commons module, database module etc and gives the revised .exe in the target folder of one of the modules (winexe module).

Many modules are interdependent on each other hence if I exclude any module from the pom my changes are not reflected. Is there any other command or way for this to be done for local development because it takes a long time during development even if there are small changes.

Comment: Not cleaning may save you some time, it should incrementally compile in most cases. Then try to go only to the module that has actually changed and do `mvn install -DskipTests`. It should build and install that project only. Finally, you may skip the actual .exe bundling, it should not be necessary for development. Putting the relevant configuration in a profile might be an option. All the above depend on the details of your setup of course.

Comment: A good IDE should only recompile the bits that have actually changed when developing.  What do you currently use?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I use eclipse (4.20.0)

Comment: It has been a while since I switched to IntelliJ so I cannot help you set up Eclipse properly for you to benefit from what it can help you with.  I would suggest opening a new question where you describe your project in more detail and ask for advice on how to set Eclipse up correctly.   I assume you have imported your current sources as a Maven project into your workspace?